# How to restart MS SQL server right, what is best practice to do that?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, recovery, best-practices

I`m quite new to DB administration.

I have a problem when I restart SQL server, one of the databases goes into `Recovery` mode and automatically repairs the DB in 30 min. I don't know why this happens.

Here is what I did, but it seems that not enough:

I have SQL Server Microsoft SQL Server 2014 (SP2-GDR).

1. install Windows updates
2. SQL: shrink all DB and logs files
3. SQL: killed all Runtime Brocker`oв
4. SQL: stopped SQL agent
5. SQL: stopped SQL server
6. Restart Windows Server.

UPDATED :

1) How big is the database?

4.5 GB + 400MB Logs

2) Why are you restarting the instance? 
Install Windows updates, and also apps that connect to that SQL server become slower and slower with time. We restart the server once a month usually. It takes 15 minutes to start, but this time it took 45 min (while recovering DB).

3) Is this a server or a pseudo-server (desktop running Server OS)?

its virtual machine. Running on server hardware.

4) Is the Server configured for application or background processes?

The server runs SQL and additional background apps/ web services

5) How much RAM does the server have? How many processors?

16 GB RAM 
4 CPU

6) SAN storage or local disks? .... The more details you provide the better we can provide you with an adequate answer.

We buy hosting as service, can`t tell exact hardware architecture. But we have SSD disk (where SQL DB stored).

7) 30 Minutes might well be the best SQL Server can do. It depends on a lot of factors.

It usually takes up to 15 min. I think I miss some steps that I need to do to close all DB in right way.

Comment: You say one of the reasons to restart the server is because apps become slower and slower with time, but restarting the server should make things even worse for every time a SQL Server is restarted it needs to read data from disk again. When the server is slow do you use any tool to check what's going on with the server? Is there any information on SQL Server log around the time it took so long in recovery mode?

Answer (score 1):

You almost certainly have a very large number of virtual log files (VLFs) in the problematic log file of the database in question.  Shutting down and restarting SQL Server causes the recovery process to run on all databases on the instance.  For databases that have a very large number of VLFs this process can be agonizingly slow.

You can see the VLFs via this DBCC command:

```
DBCC LOGINFO;
```

Each row represents one VLF.  How many do you have?  I'm betting you have a very high number of VLFs (rows).

You can rebuild the log file to remove the excess VLFs; simply shrink the log file, then grow it in sensible increments to the prior size.

I wrote a blog post showing how to do that [here](https://www.sqlserverscience.com/recovery/fix-high-vlf-count).

If you're concerned about shutting down the SQL Server instance without causing recovery to run, you can issue this command before you shut down SQL Server:

```
shutdown;
```

However, if there are existing connections, the command will wait until all connections are closed.  See the [Microsoft docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/shutdown-transact-sql?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(shutdown_TSQL);k(sql13.swb.tsqlresults.f1);k(sql13.swb.tsqlquery.f1);k(MiscellaneousFilesProject);k(DevLang-TSQL)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver15) for more detail.  `SHUTDOWN WITH NOWAIT;` will cause SQL Server to immediately shutdown, without waiting for existing connections to close, however this will trigger recovery at the next startup, and is exactly what happens when you shutdown the instance via the control panel, or via shutting down the server itself.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you stop using the database before shutting it down.
This way, it will drastically reduce the amount of transactions to rollback/forward on startup if the database has been shutdowned in an inproper way.

Usually, this is done by shutting down the application that uses the database BEFORE shutting down the database itself.

After this is done, try to shutdown the instance with `shutdown;` first.
If it's not working, then you probably still have some sessions hanged on your instance, either kill them, or `shutdown with nowait;` which will cause the instance to recover on startup.

If the amount of transactions to rollback/forward is not high, and you still encounter a big recovery time on startup.
It could be due to a high amount of Virtual LogFiles.
You can reduce those by shrinking the transaction log file and set it back to a proper size, then parameter it so it increases by a big enough size each time, instead of small portions.

**SQL Server 2019 :**

If you were on SQL Server 2019, you could also consider redesigning the SQL database engine recovery process to use ADR (Accelerated Database recovery) **if none of the previous solutions worked**.

**References :**

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/sql-server-transaction-log-architecture-and-management-guide?view=sql-server-ver15#physical_arch

[ADR]

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/accelerated-database-recovery-concepts?view=sql-server-ver15

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/restore-and-recovery-overview-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15#adr